# Rails 3 ActiveRecord Query Syntax for Date Column Plus Integer Column Less Than Today's Date

Tags: sql, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2

My application keeps track of events in the database that have a date and a duration. I am trying to query all of the events with a status of "Upcoming" that have a date plus duration that are less than today. So far I have tried:

```
events = Event.where('status = "Upcoming" and date <= (? + duration)', Date.parse(Time.now.to_s))
```

where date is my date column, and duration is an integer representing the number of days that the event runs for. The above query produces an empty set, and a MySQL warning "Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: '2013-05-09'

Database is currently MySQL, but may change in the future.

I found a SQL query that will provide the correct results, but it does not feel Railsy enough for me due to the date_add() call:

```
SELECT `events`.* FROM `events` WHERE (status = "Upcoming" and date_add(date, interval 2 day) <= '2013-05-09');
```

If I had to, I would use the date_add() function, but I do not know how the Rails syntax to produce such a query. Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a solution but not a really fast one:

```
Event.where(status: 'Upcoming').select{|e| (e.date + e.duration.days) < Date.today}
```

If I were you I'd change the table structure and the model. You could use the `before_save` hook to update a new field which is the end of the Event (date + duration.days). Than you could use just ActiveRecord to get the results and it would be fast.

Have a look at 
http://xyzpub.com/en/ruby-on-rails/3.2/ar_sonstiges.html#ar_callbacks
for more information about the `before_save` callback.

Comment: Solves the problem perfectly! Speed is not really an issue here, as the query is being done in a daily background job that is scheduled using resque and resque-scheduler. I like the idea of the model change and hook. Thank you!

Comment: I was looking for a Rails way to express `date_add()` as well. The problem is with millions of users, this will require loading them in memory and might overrun a cloud instance.